# How to create pdf file in centos by using libharu

Tags: linux, gcc

I'm trying to generate pdf file by using libharu library but i have compiled the code its creates objective file  while run that executable file its giving

***error like :undefined reference 'print_grid'***

first i export the path:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/lib/libhpdf.so"
```

and compiled

```
gcc -c text_demo.c -o text_demo.o

gcc text_demo.o -L"/usr/loca/lib" -lhpdf -o "text_demo.exe"
```

Comment: What are the contents of `text_demo.c`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1) Make sure you've actually installed libhpdf.so into /usr/local/lib

2) Compile and link:  `gcc -Wall -g  text_demo.c -L/usr/local/lib -lhpdf -o text_demo`

Note that you do *not* need "exe", you do *not* need the extraneous quote marks.

Also note that $PATH has nothing to do your your shared library path.  That's for Windows; Linux uses $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

3) Type `ldd text_demo`

This checks any runtime dependencies

4) Finally, try running your program: `./text_demo`

5) Please copy/paste any EXACT error messages during your build, ldd or execute.

Comment: its gving still same error [root@hemanth demo]# LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
[root@hemanth demo]# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
[root@hemanth demo]# gcc -Wall -g text_demo.c -L/usr/local/lib -lhpdf -o text_demo
/tmp/ccjsFLyt.o: In function `main':
/home/hemanth/libharu-libharu-ec89be4/demo/text_demo.c:129: undefined reference to `print_grid'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
[root@hemanth demo]# ldd text_demo
ldd: ./text_demo: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

You need to install libharu and libharu-devel package

Please find apperopriate pakage from here for centos 5 or cent os 6

http://pkgs.org/search/libharu

And then compile your source code

Comment: Have you install libharu and libharu-devel package ??

Comment: compile with this command gcc -Wall -g -I/usr/include/ text_demo.c -L/usr/lib/ -o text_demo -lhpdf